# Calculate a simple angle

Tags: c#

I'm calculating the angle using 2 points of a square.

The angle works well but it gives me values from -180 to 180 and it's hard for me to code the direction of my robot. **I wanted the angle only with position values ex: 0 - 360**;

```
var deltay = pontos_quadrado[0].Y - pontos_quadrado[1].Y;
var deltax = pontos_quadrado[1].X - pontos_quadrado[0].X;
angulo = Math.Atan2(deltay, deltax) * 180 / Math.PI;

angulo = Math.Round(angulo, 0);
```

Comment: `if(angulo < 0) angulo += 360;`? You want it modulo 360?

Comment: @Kroltan: you cannot just add 180 - 0 degrees would then become 180 degrees which is wrong. Starting from 0 then -1 degrees in -180 to 180 situation equates to 359 degrees in 0 - 359 - Maximillians answer is the correct way.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt wouldn't that just end up being equivalent to taking the absolute value, or am I misreading this?

Comment: @EJoshuaS If you take `abs(-90) = 90` then you can see that taking `abs()` is wrong. That would be a mirroring about the y-axis. It must be *mod 360*: The angle doesn't change if you add one full revolution (360 degress) to it. Thus `-90°` is equivalent to `-90° + 360° = 270°`, which is now in the desired positive range of `0° to 360°`. In other words we want the smalles positive equivalent representative of `angle (mod 360)`.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Yes, you are correct, I was misreading it. My point wasn't that you *ought* to do the absolute value BTW (since doing that would lead to obviously incorrect results).

Comment: @EJoshuaS The code above doesn't do absolute value, it really does the `mod` operation for negative values of `angulo` (only for those which have a max. value of `-360`, which is good enough for this case with `-180 <= angulo <= 180`). You can check all values and see that it's equivalent in the above case -- as I said, we really just need one addition with the modulus (`n = 360`) if `angulo < 0 && angulo >= -360` to implement the `mod`.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thanks for the clarification, I see what this is doing now - I agree with your solution BTW, I think that this solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the angle to be in the range of 0 to 360 by adding 360 and taking the remainder modulo 360.

```
var deltay = pontos_quadrado[0].Y - pontos_quadrado[1].Y;
var deltax = pontos_quadrado[1].X - pontos_quadrado[0].X;
angulo = Math.Atan2(deltay, deltax) * 180 / Math.PI;

angulo = (angulo + 360) % 360; // note this line

angulo = Math.Round(angulo, 0);
```